# Bind class member to plain-C function pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers

I have a library which sources I may not change. It has a structure that contains function pointer which is a callback for some event. Consider:

```
// library code (.h file)

typedef int (callback_function)(int arg1, double arg2);

struct callbacks_struct
{
    ...
    callback_function *callback;
    ...
};
```

I'm writing a C++ wrapper for this low-level stuff. Consider I have a class:

```
class Wrapper
{
public:
    int Callback(int arg1, double arg2);
};
```

Now I want to bind `Wrapper::Callback` to be used as a callback when creating structure `callback_struct`:

```
struct callback_struct x[] = 
{
    {
        ...
        // put a Wrapper::Callback as a callback
        ...
    },
    {0, 0, 0, 0}
}
```

Obviously, this can not be done without some intermediate function. The one way is to make a global object of `Wrapper` class and use it:

```
std::shared_ptr<Wrapper> gWrapper;

void foo()
{
    struct callback_struct x[] = 
    {
        {
            ...
            my_plain_callback,
            ...
        },
        {0, 0, 0, 0}
    }
}

int my_plain_callback(int arg1, double arg2)
{
    return gWrapper->Callback(arg1, arg2);
}
```

But I need a thread-safe solution, so using global variable seems to be a source of problems in this case.

Does anyone know better solution?

Thanks.

Comment: I have this exact problem. I want to assign a callback function to my non-static member function. Still haven't found a solution yet. std::bind won't convert to plain c function pointer type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a thread-local variable for the callback state.

Or go the hardcore route and use some platform-dependent code to generate a stub that injects the pointer.

Comment: Unfortunately, all I have is gcc 4.7.3 that doesn't support thread_local (but has a __thread that should be close enough) and the second (hardcore) way is not acceptable (this is an embedded solution and should support several platforms). Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It may help you:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <mutex>

class Wrapper
{
  typedef std::mutex mutex_type;
  typedef std::unique_lock<mutex_type> locker;
public:
  typedef boost::function<int(int,double)> call_backtype;
  static int callBackFunction(int arg1_, double arg2_)
  {
    locker l(_mutex);
    if ( my_call.empty() ) {
      throw std::runtime_error("No callback function was set!");
    }
    return my_call(arg1_,arg2_);
  }
  static void setCallBack( const call_backtype& func_ )
  {
    locker l(_mutex);
    _my_call = func_;
  }
private:
  static mutex_type _mutex;
  static call_backtype _my_call;
  Wrapper(void){}
};

class any_other_class
{
  int do_anything(int arg1_, double arg2_);
  void setThisAsCallback()
  {
    Wrapper::setCallBack(boost::bind(&any_other_class::do_anything,this,_1,_2));
  }
};

// to C interface (use the static method):
setCallBack(&Wrapper::callBackFunction);
```